# Non Blocking or Blocking assignment for a buffer?

Tags: buffer, verilog, fpga, fifo

I am trying to implement a small line buffer in Verilog. I am putting data from one end and reading it from the other side.

```
wire [29:0] temp_pixel;
reg  [29:0] temp_buffer[2:0];
```

I can use blocking assigment statements like these and it should work as expected.

```
always @(posedge TD_CLK27)
begin
temp_buffer[0] = temp_buffer[1];
temp_buffer[1] = temp_buffer[2];
temp_buffer[2] = temp_pixel;
end
```

But, can I use non-blocking statements(shown below) and still get the expected result? Or would temp_buffer[1] get overwritten by temp_buffer[2], before it was read into temp_buffer[0]?

```
always @(posedge TD_CLK27)
begin
temp_buffer[0] <= temp_buffer[1];
temp_buffer[1] <= temp_buffer[2];
temp_buffer[2] <= temp_pixel;
end
```

Would both the blocks work same, or does it compulsorily have to be blocking assignment statements and why?

Comment: Neither of these examples create buffers.  The first creates 1 flip-flop, the second creates 3 flip-flops.

Comment: @N8TRO  Could you clarify how does it create one flip flop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the blocks are different.

When you use blocking assignments,  the next statement  does not begin executing until the assignment has finished.

```
 x = #5 y + z;
```

This statement is executed as follows:

1. Evaluates the RHS expression and save the result
2. Wait for the specified delay
3. Perform  assignment

So in your case there is no delay while assigning your buffers you have created and verilog interprets it as a single flip flop.

```
x <= y + z;
```

The normal non-blocking assignment is executed as follows:

1. Evaluate the RHS expression and save the result in a temporary buffer
2. Finish executing all other events in the procedural block except for other non-blocking assignments
3. Perform the assignment at the end.

So in your second example, `temp_buffer[2]` gets the previous value of `temp_buffer[1]`. So there is a cycle delay before  which you can access the value. so there is a string of flip flops (depending on your code)before you get the actual output.

Again , the link in previous answer is an excellent paper to read.here are a few more
[Sunburst Design](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf)
[Link2](http://www.see.ed.ac.uk/~gerard/Teach/Verilog/manual/Example/lrgeEx2/cooley.html)

Answer (score 6):

This minimal example of *blocking*, notice the `=` :

```
module test(
input  data_in, clk,
output data_out
);

reg [2:0] temp;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
   temp[2] = data_in;
   temp[1] = temp[2];
   temp[0] = temp[1];
end

assign data_out = temp[0];

endmodule
```

creates 1 Flip-Flop:

[image: 1 Flip-Flop]

While *non-blocking*, notice the `<=`:

```
module test(
input  data_in, clk,
output data_out
);

reg [2:0] temp;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
   temp[2] <= data_in;
   temp[1] <= temp[2];
   temp[0] <= temp[1];
end

assign data_out = temp[0];

endmodule
```

creates 3 flip-flops:

[image: 3 Flip-Flops]

Buffers are created like this:

```
module test(
input  data_in, clk,
output data_out
);

wire [2:0] temp;

   buf(temp[2], data_in);
   buf(temp[1], temp[2]);
   buf(temp[0], temp[1]);

assign data_out = temp[0];

endmodule
```

[image]

More information [here.](http://cs.haifa.ac.il/courses/verilog/1996-CUG-presentation_nonblocking_assigns.pdf)